# Python - Tables within tables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python here, and I'm just having a hard time to separate these tables out.

When using this code to scan for files (for instance, mypath = "C:/"):

"common" is a table that contains extensions (ex. "*.exe", "*.pdf")

```
cFiles = []
cFilesFull = []
for f in common:
    if glob.glob(mypath + f):
        print(glob.glob(mypath + f))
        cFiles.append(get_file_name(glob.glob(mypath + f)[0], 0))
        cFilesFull.append(glob.glob(mypath + f))
```

I end up getting this as a result of the table, cFilesFull:

```
[['C:/install.exe'], ['C:/install.res.1028.dll', 'C:/install.res.1031.dll', 'C:/install.res.1033.dll', 'C:/install.res.1036.dll', 'C:/install.res.1040.dll', 'C:/install.res.1041.dll', 'C:/install.res.1042.dll', 'C:/install.res.2052.dll', 'C:/install.res.3082.dll'], ['C:/VC_RED.MSI'], ['C:/eula.1028.txt', 'C:/eula.1031.txt', 'C:/eula.1033.txt', 'C:/eula.1036.txt', 'C:/eula.1040.txt', 'C:/eula.1041.txt', 'C:/eula.1042.txt', 'C:/eula.2052.txt', 'C:/eula.3082.txt'], ['C:/vcredist.bmp'], ['C:/globdata.ini', 'C:/install.ini']]
```

Is there a way I could add all values to just one table, instead of separate ones?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: They are called `list`s in Python not tables.

Comment: I'm still new to this. It's hard for me to switch from Lua to Python and not call them tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob.glob` returns a sequence. Instead of appending this sequence to your `cFilesFull` list, extend the list instead.

```
cFilesFull.extend(glob.glob(mypath + f))
```

Comment: Ah. That seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extend` instead of `append`

```
cFiles, cFilesFull = [], []
for f in common:
    if glob.glob(mypath + f):
        print(glob.glob(mypath + f))
        cFiles.extend(get_file_name(glob.glob(mypath + f)[0], 0))
        cFilesFull.extend(glob.glob(mypath + f))
```

This will keep each item added to the list at the top level.

---

#### Example of `append` vs `extend` with `list`s

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> l.append([4,5])
>>> print(l)
>>> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
>>> l.extend([6, 7, 8])
>>> print(l)
>>> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6, 7, 8]
```